# R: Getting the value of an attribute

Tags: r, xpath

I would like to retrieve the value of "position" attribute from an html.

Here is a sample:

```
<message>

<meta date="20150707" expired="false" lastmod="Jul 08, 2015 08:00:03" matched="11" position="Jul 07, 2015 19:25:05" sentdate="Jul 07, 2015 19:25:05">

    <pubdate>Tue, 07 Jul 2015 23:25:05 +0000</pubdate>
    <summary>summaryhere</summary>
    <title>titlehere</title>

</meta>
<keywords>keywordshere</keywords>
<category>News</category>
</message>
```

I tried to use this code

```
date <- xpathSApply(data3,"//meta[@position]",xmlValue)
```

where data3 is the whole html source.

However, it only returns the following

```
date
 [1] "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" ""     "" "" "" "" "" ""
[30] "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" ""
```

any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
date <- xpathSApply(data3,"//meta[@position]", xmlGetAttr, 'position')
```

Comment: Im getting this error: 
Error in UseMethod("xmlValue") : 
  no applicable method for 'xmlValue' applied to an object of class "XMLAttributeVal

Comment: Sorry, I don't have `R` installed for testing. Basically the XPath expression that I've posted should work - but it seems that the method xpathSApply behaves differently. Check my update, does this work for you?